# How to hide android soft keyboard from option dialog click event in titanium?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

Hi i have this code in titanium mobile :

```
function showNetworkEditDialog(/*String*/ type, /*String*/ url, /*Row*/ selectedRow){
        var optionDialog = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog({
            title:'Type : ' + type,
            buttonNames:['Cancel', 'Ok']
        });

        var dialogView = Ti.UI.createView(_styles.get('view.dialog'));

        var lblURL = Ti.UI.createLabel(_globals.get('combine')(_styles.get('label.filter.normal'), {
            text:'URL:',
            left:'4dp'
        }));

        var txtURL = Titanium.UI.createTextField(_globals.get('combine')(_styles.get('textField'), {
            width:'100%',
            height:'40dp',
            value:url
        }));

        dialogView.add(lblURL);
        dialogView.add(txtURL);

        optionDialog.setAndroidView(dialogView);

        txtURL.addEventListener('focus',function(e){
            if (txtURL.getValue().toString() !== ''){
                txtURL.setSelection(txtURL.getValue().length,txtURL.getValue().length);
            }
        });

        optionDialog.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            Ti.UI.Android.hideSoftKeyboard(); // It's not works for me
            if (e.index === 1){ /* Ok Pressed */
                selectedRow._isEdited = true;

                selectedRow._url = txtURL.value.trim();
                selectedRow.children[1].setText(txtURL.value.trim());
            }
        });

        optionDialog.show();
    }
```

That code is showing an option dialog with textfield inside.. all i want is to hide android soft keyboard when i press OK or CANCEL button on that option dialog..

Does anyone know how to hide android keyboard when i press button OK or Cancel from optionDialog? i've tried use `Ti.UI.Android.hideSoftKeyboard()` and also use `txtUrl.blur()` but it not works for me..
Thanks Before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [blur method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-method-blur) to hide the softkeyboard.

Try to change your code as follows

```
optionDialog.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    txtURL.blur(); // Hides the softkeyboard
    if (e.index === 1){ /* Ok Pressed */
          selectedRow._isEdited = true;
          selectedRow._url = txtURL.value.trim();
          selectedRow.children[1].setText(txtURL.value.trim());
    }
});
```

Hope it helped you

Comment: hi Anand..Thanks for your answer.. i've tried using txtUrl.blur() but it not works for me.. any other idea? thanks :D

Comment: @MichaelFrans: That's wired. It should be work, since I have used it many times in my applications!!!

Comment: Hi Anand.. yup.. you're right.. that's weird.. i have created small application to test that and it works..but not works in my main application.. FYI. that function is called when i click on the tableView and my tableview is inside the view.. would that affect? thanks

Comment: No it wont. I guess there are other textField than txtURL in that window, or the previous window. If so you should blur all the textFields in the window while opening the window or dialog

Comment: I will try your suggestion on monday because i works from monday to friday and I will tell you the result.. thanks for helping me.. I will tell you ASAP after i try to blur all the textfield on my window.. Once again, Thank you..

Comment: hi Anand, my problem occured because i use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in my custom Android Manifest.. now i confused how to disable textfield autofocus problem on titanium.. maybe you have any idea? thanks..

Comment: Please check http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-windowSoftInputMode. I think you dont need to use it in Android manifest file